# Get and validate an user-input url with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

I've a form to enter a url and must check if it is a url with JavaScript.

The console in Firefox doesn't indicate any errors in the code (the debugger also, doesn't indicate anything) but it doesn't run.

I've also tried to display the input without validation but nothing

```js
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", linkfuction, false);

function linkfuction() {
  var link = document.getElementById("general-link").value;

  document.getElementById("1").innerhtml = "link";

  function ValidURL(link) {
    var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
    if (!regex.test(link)) {
      document.getElementById("1").innerhtml = "Enter a valid url";
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div style="padding-bottom: 1rem;">
  <form><input type="text" id="general-link"><input type="button" id="link" value="Download"></form>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 1.5rem">
  <p id="1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `innerhtml` should be `innerHTML`

Comment: Where/how do you call your `ValidURL` function? You don't actually use it in the code you posted.

Comment: `innerhtml` ► `innerHTML` and `ValidURL` is nested inside `linkfuction` and never triggered. The reason you saw no error is that in JavaScript if a property doesn't  exist, such as `innerhtml` it will be created during assignment. The code executed fine adding `innerhtml` with the value of the link to the element. Your nested function `ValidURL` didn't throw an error as the syntax of the embedded function is valid and you having is embedded but never called is not going to trigger an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling your `ValidURL` function.
Also you made a typo `innerhtml` should be `innerHTML`.

See snippet for a working example.

```js
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click", linkfuction, false);

function linkfuction(){
var link = document.getElementById("general-link").value;

document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "link";

var isValid = ValidURL(link)

alert(isValid);

}

function ValidURL(link) {
    var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
    if(!regex.test(link)) {
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Enter a valid url";
      return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-bottom: 1rem;"> 
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="general-link">
    <input type= "button" id="link" value="Download">
  </form>
</div>

<div style="font-size: 1.5rem">
  <p id="1"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I imagine this line should actually be using the `link` variable rather than a string: `document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "link";`

Comment: Thanks, i've solved ^^ (and thanks to all the others ^^)